# Download stops while downloading a file from a server

Tags: android, button, fragment, onclicklistener

I wrote a app where i can download a pdf file from a server.

When i click on the download button, i can see the sign on the top that its downloading, but then it stops and tells me "Download complete".

When i try to open the file or search for it in the folders, then cant find it and it tells me "file path doesnt exist".

I added the "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" and "Internet" permission in the manifest.

Do i have to add a persmission check/request in the code?

FragmentDownloads.java

```
import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;


public class FragmentDownloads extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button buttonCV;
    View view;

    public FragmentDownloads() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_downloads, container, false);
        buttonCV = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonCV);
        buttonCV.setOnClickListener(this);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://cvdatabase.000webhostapp.com/file.pdf");
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
        Long reference = downloadManager.enqueue(request);
    }
}
```

Additional Question: The object "reference" at the very end is gray. In a YouTube Video its somehow not. Im a beginner and cant figure it out why.

fragment_downloads.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="androfenix.mycvapp.FragmentDownloads">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonCV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

</FrameLayout>
```

---

SOLVED:
I had to add the directory path where the file has to be downloaded.
                .setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "filename.pdf");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend taking a look at this:

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html

In the code you've posted, I don't know where you're saving the file to so this may be a step to solve your problem.

Comment: i didnt tell the program where to save it. Thanks, Ill take a look at the link and try to figure it out.